# What happens if I disable the PPA of a specific package?

Tags: software-center, ppa, repository, software-sources

Say I went ahead and disabled the PPA I added to install the latest version of GIMP (2.8) on Precise. Would that lock the installed version until an updated package is available from the USC or would it cause the package version to be reverted to the one from the official repositories (2.6, I think?).

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disable the ppa of a specific package, without reinstalling the packages it contains, then `apt` will leave the packages at their currently installed versions until a newer version comes along.

If you would like to completely remove ppa's from your system you should use the `ppa-purge` tool. This can be installed by running `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` and you use it by running:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:owner-name/ppa-name
```

Comment: This will also downgrade the current GIMP 2.8 to the repos older GIMP 2.6, which I don't think he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

You will keep your 2.8 version of GIMP .The PPA will no longer be updated on 'apt-get update'. You will not be notified of any future versions of GIMP uploaded to the PPA.